# Executing objective-c code on remote device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wonder if I have remote iOS device, with any custom solution I can preload on it (written myself), is there a way to make it execute any custom code, like a block?

Here is what I mean:

```
// establish connection with remote device
[self connectToDevice:remoteDevice];

// send arbitary block of code and data to execute on remote device

[myDevice executeBlock:^(void)(BOOL result, NSData *data) {

// here I can write any code that uses the data
// I want this code to run on remote machine

}];

// I might get results via network, or any other way, not related
```

I do not mean run any malicious code, or my program, or something like that. I mean that I have my program already running and waiting for task to execute.

The problems I might see - Objective-c is compiled language, so having code sent does not help.
Is it possible to use some scripting language or solution to overcome this?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? Executing arbitrary code on other devices remotely won't fly with the AppStore, but stuff like RPC in lets say a multiplayer game is a-ok and pretty common.

Comment: @JustSid I'm looking into distributed computing on iOS, not really concerned about appstore

Comment: The answer is no, for Objective-C code.  Not only would Apple not allow it (for good reason), but there is no practical way to do it.  It's conceivable, however, that you could do this with something like Javascript, but the box on the other end would have to be co-operating.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're asking is possible. You can try hosting a remote service that can perform external computations and return the results back to the device. This way you can change the code on the external code whenever you want. I know Parse.com provides a decent platform to do something like that

Comment: @HotLicks yes, I'm looking at scenario where I have my code executing on both client and server already, nothing malicious and or hackery

Comment: Certainly if you've got your code on both ends, you can have the ends co-operate, assuming you can establish communications between them.

Comment: @HotLicks but the problem is that I might have many clients and my taks may differ, and recompiling clients each time will be tiresome

Comment: That's where Javascript might come in handy, though I don't know if there's a way to get it to execute outside of a browser.

Comment: you might could use bundles https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH1-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. Apple's terms of service forbid you from executing code you receive over the network.

Plus, Objective C is compiled and needs to be linked into your project. There is no facility for installing dynamically linked libraries at runtime in iOS.

You might be able to figure out a way to deliver dynamically linked libraries on a jailbroken device, but that's out of the scope of this board.

Comment: "*that's out of the scope of this board.*" this is a board about programming, not about apple's rules. It is perfectly in scope.

Comment: Fair enough. Better to say that's out of my area of expertise. I'm willing to play by Apple's rules in order to make a living doing it.

Comment: I am making a living of it. Still I can't see why that should lead to self-censorship. And as you can see on my comment under the question, apple itself publishes information how to create loadable code. It is just a tool that you can use of you do not depend on iOS or Mac app store. But seeing someone defining this site's scope by apple's lawyers is worrying.